# Migrating a console application to net core

Tags: .net-core, migration

One of my Client wants to migrate a console app (having System.Web dlls) to .Net Core. Do we have any relevant mapping tool which shows corresponding methods of System.Web to .Net Core.

Currently .Net portability analyzer only provides a compatibility report showing whether app can be ported or not, for relevant corresponding method mappings etc. client has to use MS docs and then do relevant method calls for .net core.

Any suggestions or recommendations or any tool which can provide relevant method replacements or make migration easier?.

Thanks In Advance!!!..